# How to create a logic statement for a dataframe in python with multiple conditions?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

My dataframe looks roughly like this

Job

blue-collar

management

self-employed

admin

student

technician

I want to create a new column called "trades" that will have a "yes" for every entry where the job is blue-collar or technician.

This is what I am currently using:

```
df['trades'] = np.where(df['job']=="blue-collar", 'yes', df['trades'] = np.where(df['job']=="technician", 'yes','no'))
```

But this did not work

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[:,"trades"] = "no"
df.loc[df['job']=="blue-collar","trades"] = "yes"
df.loc[df['job']=="technician","trades"] = "yes"
```

Comment: In terms of performance, I wouldn't use two conditions as you mentioned. It's better if you put them together in one.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with conditions you can do this:

```
df.loc[:,"trades"] = "No"
df.loc[(df['job']=="blue-collar")|(df['job']=="technician"),"trades"] = "Yes"
```

Wih `loc` you can add new columns to your dataframe. This method takes 2 parameters inside the brackets, the first one is the rows you want to change, so if you write `:` you are referring the whole dataframe, and the second is the name of the column.

So if you write `df['job']=="blue-collar"` as first parameter it will only change the rows that match this condition.

Comment: That works for only one of the conditions (=blue-collar), how can I make this for blue-collar AND technician?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use either [`.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) or [`.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) method with `np.where`

```
df["trades"] = np.where(
    df["job"].isin(["blue-collar", "technician"]), 
    # df["job"].str.contains("blue-collar|technicial), as an alternative
    "yes",
    "no"
)
```